# FFMPEG stream_loop with Overlay

Tags: ffmpeg

Doing live streaming using the FFMPEG.
I want to do endless loop on input stream.
Use the -stream_loop -1 option, but not work. How can I do it?

```
-re -stream_loop -1 -i "Background.mp4" -f image2pipe -i pipe:0 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0" -acodec aac -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -s 1280x720 -bufsize 8000k -maxrate 4000k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 30 -r 30 -f flv "URL"
```

Comment: "not work" is not descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is that you use a bash script to loop the script so it repeats itself forever. To do this you create a file and name it for example: **Loop.sh**

Open the file and format it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    ffmpeg "Background.mp4" -f image2pipe -i pipe:0 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0" -acodec aac -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -s 1280x720 -bufsize 8000k -maxrate 4000k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 30 -r 30 -f flv "URL"
done
```

Save the file and using the terminal (assuming you're using linux or Mac) make it executable. cd into the directory and use command

```
sudo chmod +x Loop.sh
```

Now you can run the script by simply typing `./Loop.sh` and it will execute forever (until you stop it).

`while true` to equal anything like `while 1=1` or any combinations of variables that will result `true`.